# Laravel 5.3 blank white screen no errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have gone through so many forums trying to find a solution to fix this error but non seems to be working.

Error in site-error.log

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /path/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundatio‌​n/helpers.php on line 475
```

I have assigned

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/directory
```

results for ls -al

```
drwxrwxrwx 12 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:06 .
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 06:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 app
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    1646 Oct 25 10:04 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    1412 Oct 25 10:04 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  134388 Oct 25 10:04 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 1723068 Oct 25 10:04 composer.phar
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 database
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     615 Oct 25 09:46 .env
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     491 Oct 25 10:04 .env.example
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data      61 Oct 25 10:04 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data      96 Oct 25 10:04 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     558 Oct 25 10:04 gulpfile.js
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     135 Oct 25 07:17 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  401057 Oct 25 10:04 _ide_helper.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     401 Oct 25 10:04 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     930 Oct 25 10:04 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 public
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     749 Oct 25 10:04 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 routes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     563 Oct 25 10:04 server.php 
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 storage
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:04 tests
drwxr-xr-x 34 www-data www-data    4096 Oct 25 10:06 vendor
```

I also applied

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

but am still getting the black white screen. where am i going wrong

Comment: Have you generated a unique APP_KEY? `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: And the document root of your web server is pointing to the `public` folder?

Comment: yes, it is pointing to the public folder

Comment: Could you then specify which actions you've taken up until this point? Which commands have you executed? Do you need a database and if yes, have you run your migrations? Maybe there are syntax errors in your .env file? That kind of stuff.

Comment: After pushing code to the live server, I executed `composer install`, then `php artisan migrate`, i created the .htaccess, then `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/directory`, then `sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`,  `php artisan key:generate` finally i tried to access my www.website.com and it has a black white screen

Comment: I renamed .env.example to .env and added the database credentials

Comment: What do you mean with created "the .htaccess"? Laravel already comes with a really good one in the public folder. Rest seems perfectly fine.

Comment: I am using sentora and am deploying to a subdomain,

Comment: I am deploying to a subdomain on a ubuntu server using using sentora. and the .htaccess contains `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126586/discussion-between-loek-and-william-jingo).

Comment: are you using centos or fedora? try disable your selinux first then once figure out the problem, enable back and setting your selinux to some directories in laravel project

Comment: am using sentora and the error is `I have found this error in site-error.log
`Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in  /path/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 475`

Comment: Are you sure that your PHP version is supported by Laravel?

Comment: Yes it does, the project runs properly on my local machine. And i have just upgraded to php7 on the ubuntu vps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who might be facing the same issue, after upgrading to php7 you have to disable Apache2's PHP5 module and enable PHP7, like so:

```
a2dismod php5
a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```